# Nested CSS Custom Properties (CSS Variables) with media-queries in IE 11?

Tags: css, gulp, internet-explorer-11, postcss, css-variables

My setup:

```
// Set CSS Vars
:root {
  // These variables control everything
  /* set base values */
  --text-base-size: 1.125em;
  /* This is for smaller text (sm and down) */
  --text-scale-ratio-down: 1.15;
  /* This is for larger text (md and up) */
  --text-scale-ratio-up: 1.18;

  // Calculate sizes
  --text-xxs: calc(((1em / var(--text-scale-ratio-down)) / var(--text-scale-ratio-down)) / var(--text-scale-ratio-down));
  --text-xs: calc(var(--text-xxs) * var(--text-scale-ratio-down));
  --text-sm: calc(var(--text-xs) * var(--text-scale-ratio-down));
  --text-md: calc(1em * var(--text-scale-ratio-up));
  --text-lg: calc(var(--text-md) * var(--text-scale-ratio-up));
  --text-xl: calc(var(--text-lg) * var(--text-scale-ratio-up));
  --text-xxl: calc(var(--text-xl) * var(--text-scale-ratio-up));
  --text-xxxl: calc(var(--text-xxl) * var(--text-scale-ratio-up));
  --text-xxxxl: calc(var(--text-xxxl) * var(--text-scale-ratio-up));
}

// Responsive
// Override variables for recalculation on desktops
@include mq(xxl){
    :root {
    /* set base values */
    --text-base-size: 1.313em;
    /* This is for smaller text (sm and down) */
    --text-scale-ratio-down: 1.18;
    /* This is for larger text (md and up) */
    --text-scale-ratio-up: 1.22;
  }
}

body {
  // Set base font size
  font-size: var(--text-base-size);
}

// Set font-size
h1 {
  font-size: var(--text-xxxl);
}
```

After compiling with `postcss-preset-env` it looks like that in **IE 11**:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 1.93878em;
  font-size:var(--text-xxxl);");
}
```

IE 11 does not understand custom properties and uses the value **1.93878em**. This value was statically calculated by `postcss-preset-env`.

This is correct on mobile devices! On larger desktops, the CSS variables are adjusted by the media-query and the text is displayed larger.

**This does not work here, because the IE 11 does not recognize the updating of the CSS variable in the media-query. Maybe it does not work, because the CSS variables are nested?**

What can a solution for the IE 11 look like?

Comment: IE doesn't support them : https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Comment: That's clear to me .... that's why there is postCSS.

Comment: Can you post an example which can produce the issue in Internet Explorer? We will try to test the code in IE to check the result. It can help to understand the issue in better way.

Comment: I do not know how ... It is rather that postCSS would have to write additional CSS, which takes into account the updating of the CSS variables in media-query.

Comment: It will be also difficult for us because we are not able to understand the issue properly with only above posted code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use polyfill, it helped me, get CDN in 
https://github.com/nuxodin/ie11CustomProperties

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the section in the help area about writing good answers. Link only answers are vulnerable to those links dying and an answer should be useful even if the link breaks.